# show modal after form submit issue (wtform)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jinja2, flask-wtforms

Due to my lack of knowledge and experience, like many before me, I am struggling with (probably) trivial problem:

I'm trying to lunch modal after form submit. this is my code for buttons:

```
<button type="submit" form="url_form" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-warning" onclick="document.getElementById('openModal').click();") style="margin-top:10px">Submit triggering modal_btn</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="openModal">Open Modal</button>
```

and separately, without my form, this code is working.

Code for my forms (2nd form is only as an placeholder):

```
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show bg-dark text-dark active" id="generete url">
             <form action="{{ url_for('phrase_to_db') }}" method="POST" class="form-signin" style="color:white" id="url_form">

                 {{ url_form.hidden_tag() }}
                 <h3 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">
                    <br>
                    Please enter Your URL:
                    </h3>
                    <br>
                    {{ url_form.url.label() }}
                    {{ url_form.url(class="form-control", placeholder="Your URL") }}
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" form="url_form" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-warning" onclick="document.getElementById('openModal').click();") style="margin-top:10px">Submit Your URL modal_btn</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CodeURL" id="openModal">Open Modal</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show bg-dark text-dark active" id="retrieve_url">
                <form action="{{ url_for('retrieve') }}" method="POST" class="form-signin" style="color:white" id="retrieve_url_form">
                    {{ retrieve_url_form.hidden_tag() }}
                    <h3 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">
                        <br>
                        Please enter Your Phrase:
                    </h3>
                    <br>
                    {{ retrieve_url_form.phrase.label() }}
                    {{ retrieve_url_form.phrase(class="form-control", placeholder="Your Phrase") }}
                    <br>
                    <!-- <a data-toggle="modal" href="#RetrieveModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">if RetrieveModal click here!</a> -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-info" style="margin-top:10px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RetrieveModal" id="reurl">Retrieve Your URL modal_btn</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If 1st button type is "button" modal is shown but (obviously) the form is not submitted and nothing is sent to DB.

If 1st button type is "submit" the form is submitted and data are sent to DB but the modal is not shown.

2nd button is shown for test only and he also works fine (when 1st button type="submit" and triggered manually) displaying both data that have been posted to DB by submit and success msg.

I have no idea why it doesn't work the way I want it to. I'll be thankful for any help.

Comment: The form submission and displaying a "success" message are two different things. Do the form submission first, validate/save it to the DB on the backend and then return a "success" page to the user. On the success page you can open a modal window after page load if you want using the [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) method (or using a JS framework).

Comment: Thank You Dauros for Your response.
This is an option i'm thinking of, but code for buttons in other places works fine. First button submits form and triggers second (hidden) button to lunch modal... but not in my form and i'm wonder why. Is there problem with WTForm, Jinja2 or i'm messing something in my code.